# pandasの整形加工：顧客に実施した行動により顧客の認知ステージを変化させるプログラムを作成したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

pandasの縦方向の計算が苦手で、教えていただければと思います。

シミュレーション用のデータを作成したいと考えているのですが、顧客ごとに、5つの行動をします。その5つの行動によって、顧客の認知レベルが上がるということを想定します。行動1から行動５まであった場合に、顧客ステージを0～5の6段階に分けて、初期状態では、まず顧客ステージが0を入れます。表は時系列になっています。

・顧客ステージが0の時、行動1を実施するとステージが1に上がる
・顧客ステージが1の時、行動2を実施するとステージが2に上がる
・顧客ステージが2の時、行動3を実施するとステージが3に上がる
・顧客ステージが3の時、行動4を実施するとステージが4に上がる
・顧客ステージが4の時、行動5を実施するとステージが5に上がる

5まで上がり切ったあとは顧客ステージは5のままと考えます。
また顧客ステージが1の状態で、何かステージが上がる行動ではなくても、
顧客ステージは保持されると考えます。

つまり、以下のような初期の表 (ファイル) があった場合に、

| 顧客 | 行動1 | 行動2 | 行動3 | 行動4 | 行動5 | 顧客ステージ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

というファイルがあった時に、

| 顧客 | 行動1 | 行動2 | 行動3 | 行動4 | 行動5 | 顧客ステージ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

自分で思いついたのは、以下の様なコードですが、これだと、顧客のIDを無視していることと、顧客ステージが1のあと、また0に戻ったりすることが分かっています。
恐れ入りますが、何卒、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
df["顧客ステージ2"]=df["顧客ステージ"].shift(1).fillna(0)
df.loc[(df["1"]==1),"顧客ステージ2"]=1
df["顧客ステージ3"]=df["顧客ステージ2"].shift(1).fillna(0)
df.loc[(df["2"]==1)&(df["顧客ステージ3"]==1),"顧客ステージ3"]=2
df["顧客ステージ4"]=df["顧客ステージ3"].shift(1).fillna(0)
df.loc[(df["3"]==1)&(df["顧客ステージ4"]==2),"顧客ステージ4"]=3
df["顧客ステージ5"]=df["顧客ステージ4"].shift(1).fillna(0)
df.loc[(df["4"]==1)&(df["顧客ステージ5"]==3),"顧客ステージ5"]=4
df["顧客ステージ6"]=df["顧客ステージ5"].shift(1).fillna(0)
df.loc[(df["5"]==1)&(df["顧客ステージ6"]==4),"顧客ステージ6"]=5
df.loc[df["顧客ステージ2"]==1,"顧客ステージ"]=1
df.loc[df["顧客ステージ3"]==2,"顧客ステージ"]=2
df.loc[df["顧客ステージ4"]==3,"顧客ステージ"]=3
df.loc[df["顧客ステージ5"]==4,"顧客ステージ"]=4
df.loc[df["顧客ステージ6"]==4,"顧客ステージ"]=5
df= df.顧客op(['顧客ステージ2',"顧客ステージ3","顧客ステージ4","顧客ステージ5","顧客ステージ6"],axis=1)
```

Comment: 上から行ごとに反復処理したいということで合ってますか？ その場合 pandasの縦方向の計算, とかじゃなく, pandasにあまり関係なさそうにも思えます

Comment: 行動1, 行動2 など複数同時に 1になることはあるのでしょうか？ 数値は 2 以上もあるのでしょうか？

Comment: oriri様、コメントありがとうございます。上から行ごとに見るのですが、一つ上の状態を見る必要があると考えております。行動は1回について1つと考えております。なにとぞ、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: oriri様、ご指摘ありがとうございました。記述ミスでした。1つ空白の欄ができてしまって、ステージ5が見えなくなってしまいました。直しております。見ていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

```py
from functools import reduce

df['顧客ステージ'] = (
  df.groupby('顧客', sort=False).apply(lambda x:
    pd.DataFrame(
      reduce(lambda a, b: a + [a[-1] + ((b - a[-1]) == 1)],
             x.filter(regex=r'^行動')
              .multiply(range(1, 6), axis=1).sum(axis=1).values,
             [0])[1:], index=x.index)))

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

| 顧客 | 行動1 | 行動2 | 行動3 | 行動4 | 行動5 | 顧客ステージ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

Comment: melian様、回答ありがとうございます。今回出した、私の例が少し簡単化しすぎたものだったと思うのですが、いただいたコードを実行したところ、どのような行動をとったかに関わらず、顧客ごとの顧客ステージが順番に1,2,3,4,5と上がっていく形になっておりました。私の例が悪かったのですが、実際の行動のパターンは、種々のパターンで、順番に顧客ステージが上がらない可能性があるため、書き直しました。回答いただいたことに深く感謝いたします。もし、よろしかったら、一緒に考えていただけますと幸いです。お詫びいたしますとともに、感謝いたします。なにとぞ、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

pandasらしくない, ほぼ Python版

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
       ['A', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ['A', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ['A', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       ['B', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       ['B', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ['B', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       ['A', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       ['A', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       ['A', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       ['A', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       ['A', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ],
    columns=['顧客', '行動1', '行動2', '行動3', '行動4', '行動5'])

cli = dict.fromkeys(df['顧客'].unique(), 0)
for k, *a in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
    s = cli[k]
    if s < 5 and a[s] >= 1:   # while あるいは if
        s += 1
        cli[k] = s
    print(k, *a, s)
```

こちらは pandasぽく記述できた(と思う)コード

- colabで動かしてるため, `(row > 0)` 2回記述してるが, 比較的新しい Pythonならば セイウチ演算子利用可能かもしれない
- `selectors`は [itertools.compress](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) の逆, dataからフィルター作る関数。pandas/NumPy に同様の機能があれば置き換えたいが, 見つからないようなため

```py
def selectors(data, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    n = next(it)
    for d in data:
        b = d == n
        yield b and 1 or 0
        if b: n = next(it, None)

# (`df.v` は「行動n」を示すワーク, 不要なので処理後は削除してよい)
df['v'] = df.loc[:, '行動1':'行動5'].apply(lambda row:
        (row > 0).argmax() if (row > 0).any() else -1, axis=1)
df['ステージ'] = df.groupby('顧客').apply(lambda sdf:
        pd.Series(selectors(sdf.v, range(5)), index=sdf.index).cumsum()).droplevel(0)

display(df.drop(columns='v'))
```

Comment: oriri様、ご連絡がおそくなってすみません。pandasではないという意味がよくわかりました。なかなかこのレベルには達することができませんが、御礼申し上げます。